# Box2DX: How to prevent body tunneling at high velocities?

Tags: c#, box2d, collision-detection

I'm making pong, and have problems with player body tunneling inside other objects
when moving using SetLinearVelocity.

My collisions work fine apart from the tunneling. The player tunnels inside or even through
top and bottom walls. Player is a dynamic body, the walls are static bodies.

This is my mouse movement code for player:

```
Vec2 playerVelocity = new Vec2();
float mousePosY = Mouse.GetPosition(window).Y / PixelsToMeter;
float playerPosY = this.Body.GetPosition().Y;

// Player collides with wall
if (this.collisionWithWall)
{
    playerVelocity.Y = 0;
}
else
{
    if (mousePosY - playerPosY > 0.01f || mousePosY - playerPosY < -0.01f)
    {
        // I have a fixed timestep of 1 / 60, so 
        // multiplying by 60 makes the movement smooth.
        // This also means that the velocity is very high.
        playerVelocity.Y = (mousePosY - playerPosY) * 60;
    }
    else if (mousePosY - playerPosY == 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.Y = 0;
    }
}
this.playerBody.SetLinearVelocity(playerVelocity);
```

The player is made up of 3 shape definitions, like this:

```
// Define new shape definitions
this.rightShape = new PolygonDef() { UserData = "side", IsSensor = true, Density = 1.0f };
// (4px, 124px) fixture at (player.body: 22, 2)
this.rightShape.SetAsBox(2f / PixelsToMeter, (HalfHeight - 2) / PixelsToMeter, new Vec2(10 / PixelsToMeter, 2 / PixelsToMeter), 0);

this.topShape = new PolygonDef() { UserData = "top", IsSensor = true, Density = 1.0f };
// (24px, 4px) fixture at (player.body: 0, 0)
this.topShape.SetAsBox(HalfWidth / PixelsToMeter, 2 / PixelsToMeter, new Vec2(-12 / PixelsToMeter, -HalfHeight / PixelsToMeter), 0);

this.bottomShape = new PolygonDef() { UserData = "bottom", IsSensor = true, Density = 1.0f };
// (24px, 4px) fixture at (player.body: 0, 128)
this.bottomShape.SetAsBox(HalfWidth / PixelsToMeter, 2f / PixelsToMeter, new Vec2(-12 / PixelsToMeter, HalfHeight / PixelsToMeter), 0);
```

I have set the player body as bullet, for continuous collision detection.

```
this.playerBody.SetBullet(true);
```

Wall shape definition:

```
// Define a new shape definition
this.wallPoly = new PolygonDef();
this.wallPoly.IsSensor = true;
this.wallPoly.SetAsBox(HalfWidth / PixelsToMeter, HalfHeight / PixelsToMeter);
```

I have confirmed that the problem is indeed the high velocity, when moving the body
with slower velocity the collision works great, but after setting the velocity gradually
higher the tunneling becomes more and more obvious. At the moment when I move my mouse
very fast up or down, the player tunnels right through the walls to the other side,
without stopping at all.

**How to prevent tunneling at high velocities?**

Comment: A workaround would be to simulate multiple steps with a smaller velocity (or just with a smaller time step) instead of one step with the full velocity.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me find the solution. I had read another stackoverflow question regarding my problem, but couldn't connect the dots. After I read your comment, I searched for that question and understood how to implement it to my needs. How should I proceed, can I accept your comment as the right answer.. or?